# All requests using Volley give TimeoutError

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to make some basic requests. However every request is returning a Timeout error. I have tried a number of different urls. My device is connected to the internet. I am connected via a WiFi pairing in Android Studio. I have given my app the `INTERNET` permission. I have tried overriding the timeout to 30s and it still happens:

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val basicRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://google.com", 
    {Log.w("APP", "SUCCESS")},
    {Log.e("APP", it.stackTraceToString())})
queue.add(basicRequest)
```

```
2022-03-04 21:09:20.173 2924-2966/com.myapp D/Volley: [286] WaitingRequestManager.maybeAddToWaitingRequests: new request, sending to network 1-https://google.com
2022-03-04 21:09:21.211 2924-2924/com.myapp E/APP: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:162)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
2022-03-04 21:09:21.212 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (1043 ms) [ ] https://google.com 0xa46e044c NORMAL 2
2022-03-04 21:09:21.213 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [ 2] add-to-queue
2022-03-04 21:09:21.213 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (+2   ) [286] cache-queue-take
2022-03-04 21:09:21.214 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [286] cache-miss
2022-03-04 21:09:21.215 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (+3   ) [290] network-queue-take
2022-03-04 21:09:51.216 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (+1035) [290] socket-timeout-giveup [timeout=30000]
2022-03-04 21:09:51.217 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [290] post-error
2022-03-04 21:09:51.217 2924-2924/com.myapp D/Volley: [2] MarkerLog.finish: (+3   ) [ 2] done
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `INTERNET` permission, you need to completely uninstall the app from your device. After doing this and reloading it, it connects fine.